# Got error: strides should be of length 1, 3 or 5 but was 2 for 2D CNN - LSTM

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, conv-neural-network

I tried to use CNN LSTM to classify but I got this error message: strides should be of length 1, 3 or 5 but was 2 for 2D CNN - LSTM. Here is my code:

```
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2],X_train.shape[3] ))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1], X_test.shape[2],X_test.shape[3]))
print("build model...")
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation='relu',data_format="channels_last"),
        input_shape = X_train.shape))
model.add(TimeDistributed( Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same',  activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D((2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(256, return_sequences=False, dropout=0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=10, epochs=70, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Please help me fix it. Thanks!